# iOS: how to add image on view programmatically?

Tags: ios

I am trying to add an image to my view programmatically but I dont know how , only using storyboards.

I am a newbie so any help would be appreciated

Any one could help ?

Comment: what you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello sir so this you have to add in your (.h File)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *yourImage;
```

And this in your ViewController (.m File)

```
        self.yourImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(floatX,floatY,widthX,heightY)];
        self.yourImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename"];
```

EDIT: at the end you have to

```
[self.view addSubview:self.yourImage];
```

Comment: Hmm thanks sir it works do i have to specify the extension too ?

Comment: No dont use extensions, just add the image in Supporting Files Group

Comment: No. Put the image in the asset catalog. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Create your image view object and add it on main view.

```
UIImageView  *yourImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,Width,height)];

[self.view addSubview:yourImage];
```

Done
:)